# Celery - Obtain the Task ID in task_success signal?

Tags: python, signals, celery

I have an application that implements the `task_success` signal like this:

```
@signals.task_success.connect
def task_success_handler(sender=None,result=None,**kwargs):
    print("**************************C100")
    pprint.pprint(sender.name)
    print("**************************C100")
```

I can obtain the task name. Is there any way to obtain the `task_id`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#task-success), `sender` is the task object executed. Task object has `request` attribute which has all the information related to the task.

To get `task_id`, you can do `sender.request.id` access.

```
@signals.task_success.connect
def task_success_handler(sender=None,result=None,**kwargs):
    print(sender.request.id)
```