# Implementation of order management service using Celey+RabbitMQ+Redis

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I've implemented the functionality of packing up some files into `.zip` file on the fly using `zipstream` and, thus the response is in format of `mimetype='application/zip'` using **Flask**. Now I want to implement the service of submitting orders (i.e. tasks of generating `.zip` files), tracking state of orders (e.g. `STARTED`, `SUCCESS`, `FAILURE`), revoking orders (i.e. cancelling tasks of generating `.zip` files or deleting generated `.zip` files), and downloading orders (i.e. `.zip` files) for a current user. And I plan to use **Celery** with **RabbitMQ** being message broker and **Redis** being result backend.

Here come the question. Is is sufficient for just **Redis** being result backend ? Because tracking state of a user's orders seem to involve in query like `user = ...` more than support of `AsyncResult` query by *task id*

**UPDATED:**
Thanks to @Tomáš Linhart. I follow that extended way of storing results in **MongoDB** using `signal handler mechanism` of celery. Here's snippet of code related to task I created. The way I created instance of `task_tracker` and `celery_cli` is same as `tracker` and `app` in @Tomáš Linhart 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281347/is-it-possible-to-extend-celery-so-results-would-be-store-to-several-mongodb-co/60300906#60300906).

```
# Import task_tracker and celery_cli here
...

@task_tracker.track
@celery_cli.task(name='pack-up-tif')
def async_pack_up_tif(**kwargs):
    # Some processing here
    ...

def pack_up_tif(msg):
    result = async_pack_up_tif.delay(**msg)
    return result
```

But I still have one problem. How to intercept task id when calling `delay` method ? Because I need that info to be stored in collection of MongoDB via `find_one_and_update` when `task_success` signal being triggered.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60300906/5832540. For your use case, which was similar to mine, simple result backend is not enough as you need to store attributes that Celery doesn't know (e.g. user ID, order ID etc.)

Comment: Thanks @TomášLinhart . Your post does help me a lot :) .

Comment: @TomášLinhart I followed your answer but still stuck in problems, and I've updated this post. Any more explaination can you offer ? Thanks.

Comment: I posted an anwer which should give you a hint how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment I posted and answer your updated question. It's a bit involving to determine where from to gather the various data you'd like to track in each of the signal. Some signals provide you with the task itself, some with the task request.

I ended with this handler for `task_success` signal:

```
def _on_task_success(self, sender, result, **other_kwargs):
    if sender.name not in self.tasks:
        return

    collection = self.mongo \
        .get_database(self.config['mongodb']['database']) \
        .get_collection(self.config['mongodb']['collection'])
    collection.find_one_and_update(
        {'_id': sender.request.id},
        {
            '$setOnInsert': {
                'name': sender.name,
                'args': sender.request.args,
                'kwargs': sender.request.kwargs
            },
            '$set': {
                'status': states.SUCCESS,
                'date_done': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                'retries': sender.request.retries,
                'group_id': sender.request.group,
                'chord_id': sender.request.chord,
                'root_id': sender.request.root_id,
                'parent_id': sender.request.parent_id,
                'result': result
            },
            '$push': {
                'status_history': {
                    'date': datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
                    'status': states.SUCCESS
                }
            }
        },
        upsert=True,
        return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

Comment: Thanks. And shortly a while before, I just find that solution about retrieving task id using `sender.request.id` as well from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541590/celery-obtain-the-task-id-in-task-success-signal) here. And I found that `celery.uuid` can be applied on `delay(..., task_id=uuid())`. So I can close this problem now. Thank for your patience anyway :)